# Only getting the data of the last item when mapping over an array in React

Tags: reactjs, closures

There are two projects - the first one has ID = 69 and the second one's is 70. The function **renderToolTipButtons** takes in a **list of buttons** and renders(sample below). The problem I am facing is when the page renders, the data for project ID on **Line 6** consoles correctly, 69 and then 70. But when i actually clicked on the rendered button, **Line 14** displays only the project ID of the second project, which is **always 70**... I believe this has something to do with closure?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
   return [
      {
        text: 'Button 1',
        icon: <EditIcon fontSize="small" />,
        color: '#272727',
        callback: handleEditProject,
      },
      {
        text: 'Button 2',
        icon: <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" />,
        color: '#c12026',
        callback: handleLeaveProject,
      },
    ];
```

```
export default function CustomToolTip(props) {
  const { open, anchorEl, index, tooltipButtons, projectID } = props;

  const renderTooltipButtons = buttons => {
    return buttons.map((button, index) => {
      console.log(projectID); // LINE 6 **  This console log shows 69 and 70 when the components render **

      return (
        <React.Fragment key={index}>
          <Button
            onClick={event => {
              event.stopPropagation();
              // button.callback(projectID) -> The goal is to call something like this, but projectID always refers to the last project ID, 70. 
              console.log(projectID); // LINE 14 **** Always the ID of the last item, which is 70 upon clicked ****
            }}
            startIcon={button.icon}
          >
            <span style={{ color: button.color }}>{button.text}</span>
          </Button>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <Popper
      modifiers={{
        preventOverflow: {
          enabled: false,
          boundariesElement: 'viewport',
        },
      }}
      id={index}
      placement="bottom-end"
      open={open}
      anchorEl={anchorEl}
    >
      <Paper elevation={0}>{renderTooltipButtons(tooltipButtons)}</Paper>
    </Popper>
  );
}
```

Comment: in your `props` what content of `projectID`? a Number?

Comment: If `projectID` is a prop on the parent component then it should always only be one number (either 69 or 70) when you click either of the buttons. My guess is its logging 69 and 70 on line 6 because you're rendering two <CustomToolTip /> components somewhere? Can you create a codesandbox for this?

Comment: @LiuLei Yes , it would be a Number.

Comment: @Barryman9000 There's a lot of configuration in the codebase with Babel and stuff so i am not sure how to go about it but here it is https://jsfiddle.net/qx6yhd4f/

I am only rendering one tool tips (although the name tooltips can be misleading due to naming 0.0, more like a popover when click on an icon) for each projects.